# How long to wait to bottle after adding sulfites?

Tags: bottling, oxidation, potassium-meta-bisulfite

When adding sulfites to a wine, mead, or cider prior to bottling for oxidation prevention, how long should you wait after adding the sulfites before transferring to bottles? Is there a set amount of time, or are you pretty much good to go immediately?

Note, this is not a question about stabilizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the campden tablets and once they have dissolved you are good to go with your bottling. For further reading: http://www.eckraus.com/blog/add-campden-tablets-to-wine

Comment: That's what I figured. I thought I'd ask anyway, since there wasn't really any info here on Homebrew SA